# Getting an error when I try to run "foundation new myApp" when using Foundation for Apps

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation

I am trying to install [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps.html). Installation completed successfully but when I run this command `foundation new myApp`, I get this error below.

I am on a Mac 10.11. Node v5.3.0. NPM v3.3.12

```
module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
```

From Node.js perspective the above error is a clear indicator of a missing module. In order to `npm install config-chain` but it may be different in your case.

Having googled your issues, I came across a few similar errors listed below:

**Similar Issue in drifty/ionic**

There is also a github [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/656) in `drifty/ionic` (maybe un-related but, discusses same problem) where a similar issue has been discussed. I would recommend that you follow up the instructions provided in the github issue and see if that fixes your problem.

**Similar error in Foundation CLI**

Please look at this [issue](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36973-install-foundation-cli) and see he solution that indicate re-installing foundation might help resolve the issue.

**Possible bug in Foundation CLI**

This [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/721) describes a similar issue (scroll to the middle to see `config-chain` issue) to yours and it has been marked as *bug* in the CLI.

**May or May not be releted but, worth a read**

This issue also addresses issues starting the app.